# mysql changing unique key to primary (mariadb)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, primary-key, myisam, unique-key

I have my table users:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid             | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lname              | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fname              | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| system_id          | varchar(12)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and I want to change the `system_id` and the `userid` to be unique keys.

If I change them via `ALTER TABLE users MODIFY userid varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY;` I get:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid             | varchar(30)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lname              | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fname              | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| system_id          | varchar(12)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and then if I change the system_id `ALTER TABLE users MODIFY system_id varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY;`

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid             | varchar(30)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lname              | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fname              | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| system_id          | varchar(12)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why is MySQL changing my `UNIQUE` key to `PRI` when I never specified it to?

Comment: I suspect the first unique key is automatically made the primary key by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A UNIQUE index may be displayed as PRI if it cannot contain NULL values and there is no PRIMARY KEY in the table. A UNIQUE index may display as MUL if several columns form a composite UNIQUE index; although the combination of the columns is unique, each column can still hold multiple occurrences of a given value."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Found my answer.

Comment: It is best to explicitly specify a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It is rare to have two `UNIQUE` keys in a table.

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer to make this easier to find when searching.